# Why as increase thread contetion Interlocked is slower?

Tags: multithreading, caching, lock-free, interlocked

My question is very simple.

Why Interlocked-Increment in multi-thread is slower than 1-thread?

Is it just because of Cache line bouncing(Cache line contention)?

Or is there another reason?

I'm using Intel i7, visual studio 2012. 
I tested counting number using Interlocked-Increment function. and test result was that.

1 Thread - 610385971

2 Thread - 497804468

3 Thread - 351516659

4 Thread - 333275249

Comment: Your question as worded is vague and unanswerable. You haven't shown us your code, which could be slow for other reasons; you haven't told us what platform/hardware architecture you're running on; and you haven't given us any numbers showing the performance you're seeing. Please see the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for information on how to ask your question better.

Comment: I'm very sorry! 
I'm using Intel i7,  visual studio 2012.
I tested counting number using Interlocked-Increment function.
and test result was that.

1 Thread - 610385971
2 Thread - 497804468
3 Thread - 351516659
4 Thread - 333275249

in this test, as you see, as thread increase performance is down.
I just wonder what reason of performance down.
have a nice day!

Comment: Put those notes in your original post.

Comment: Thank you! I followed your advise!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the code from your verbal description correctly, then yes, main reason for performance degradation is competition for same cache line between different cores. I.e., for successful execution of interlocked increment a core must get cache line to E using something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESIF_protocol that is require inter-core coordination and so visible slower in comparison to execution of interlocked increment on single core.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought there is another main reason for performance degradation! I should study cache more :)

Comment: @chfhrqnfRhc: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393850/can-num-be-atomic-for-int-num for more about the low-level details of how CPUs implement the x86 asm instruction `lock inc [mem]` internally, and why it's atomic but `inc [mem]` isn't (without the x86 `lock` prefix), and how this matters for C atomics.